Extensions of functions with bounded $\int \lvert\operatorname{div} A(\nabla u)\rvert\, dm$
Consider the annulus $\mathcal A:= B(0,2)\setminus B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R^n$, $n\geq2$  and the divergence form elliptic operator $\operatorname{div}(A\nabla \cdot)$ on $\mathcal A$ where $A$ is a uniformly elliptic matrix with $L^\infty$ coefficients.
My question is: given any linear function $L\cdot x$ with $\lvert L\rvert\leq1$ (in whatever reasonable vector norm you want to consider), does there exist a continuous function $u$ on $\overline{\mathcal A}$ satisfying

$u\rvert_{\partial B_1} = L\cdot x$,
$u\rvert_{\partial B_2} = 0$,
$\lvert\operatorname{div}(A\nabla u)\rvert(\overline{\mathcal A}) \leq C$ where the LHS is understood as a measure and the constant $C$ only depends on the ellipticity and $L^\infty$ bounds of the matrix $A$?

If $A$ is the identity (or very regular) the answer is easy as any $C^2$ extension will work, but I wonder what happens with more general operators….

Let me be a bit more precise: the function $u$ is equal to $Lx$ in $B_1$, to $0$ in $B_2^c$ and I'm interested in the quantity $|\operatorname{div}(A\nabla u)|(\overline{\mathcal A})$.

TeX note: usually | | work just fine as norm delimiters, but, every so often, TeX needs to know explicitly which is an opening delimiter and which is a closing delimiter. Note $|\operatorname{div}(A\nabla u)|$ |\operatorname{div}(A\nabla u)| versus $\lvert\operatorname{div}(A\nabla u)\rvert$ \lvert\operatorname{div}(A\nabla u)\rvert.  I edited accordingly.  (While I was there, I also changed $B(0, 2) \backslash B(0, 1)$ B(0, 2) \backslash B(0, 1) to $B(0, 2) \setminus B(0, 1)$ B(0, 2) \setminus B(0, 1).)
